# go printing array of structs prints only pointer values

Tags: go

With the following code

```
checks := checkDeployment.CheckAll().All()
fmt.Printf("checks: %+v\n", checks[0])
fmt.Printf("checks: %+v\n", checks)
```

I got this output

```
checks: &{name:CheckUpdateStrategy serviceState:0 message:everything ok}
checks: [0xc42050b9e0]
```

Why the array is printed as the value of a pointer and not formatted like a single element?

```
type (
    // ServiceCheckResults contains multiple results for service checks
    ServiceCheckResults interface {
        All() []ServiceCheckResult
    }

    serviceCheckResultsImpl struct {
        results map[string]ServiceCheckResult
    }
)

// All returns all values from the set
func (r *serviceCheckResultsImpl) All() []ServiceCheckResult {
    values := []ServiceCheckResult{}
    for _, value := range r.results {
        values = append(values, value)
    }
    return values
}
```

Comment: Because they _are_ pointers. The `fmt` output doesn't recurse indefinitely.

Comment: Because that's how it is implemented. Although you can implement the Stringer interface on your pointer type.

Comment: sorry I'm new to go, how I must change my code?

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: @BenKeil in this example `*T` implements the Stringer interface by virtue of implementing the String method: https://play.golang.org/p/xMwm7ZUbfjH (comment out the method to see the difference)

Comment: @mkopriva thank you, that solved my problem. I thought there must be a way without implement the `String()` function.

Comment: Try the `%#v` format specifier after dereferencing the pointer